# How do I create a node with childnodes using SQlite & Javascript?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I'm trying to build an app with Electron and a database called SQlite. I would like to create a list of titles and subtitles from multiple tables. It needs to look like this:

```
**Titlename 1**
- Subname 1
- Subname 2
- Subname 3

**Titlename 2**
- Subname 4
- Subname 5
- Subname 6
```

This is my code:

```
db.serialize(() => {

var rows = document.getElementById("database");

db.each("SELECT DISTINCT titlename, Subname FROM sqlitedatabase ORDER BY Titleorder", function(err,row) {

// The results from the database (the titlename) are put into <p id="chaptertitle">
var item = document.createElement("p");
item.setAttribute("id", "chaptertitle");
item.textContent = row.chapname;

// The results of the subchapter column go into a second variable:  
var item2 = document.createElement("p");
item2.setAttribute("id", "subchaptertitle");
item2.textContent = row.Subchapter;

// Then both <p>-elements are put into the <div id='database'>
rows.appendChild(item);
rows.appendChild(item2);

});
});

// and we close the database
db.close();
```

The result is not quite what I had in mind:

```
        <div id="database">
    <p id="chaptertitle">Titlename 1</p>
    <p id="subchaptertitle">Subname 1</p>
    <p id="chaptertitle">Titlename 1</p>
    <p id="subchaptertitle">Subname 2</p>
    </div>
```

How can I fix this? I think I need to use some kind of loop,  but I can't figure out how to do this. Something like 'foreach chaptertitle select corresponding subtitle'. Can you help me?

Comment: Anyone? Is there any documentation or direction I should look at?

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking how to join multiple tables in the query, or how to process chaptertitle in the js only when it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question:

I added the childnodes to the wrong parents. This works:

```
// The results of the subchapter column go into a second variable  
var item2 = document.createElement("p");
item2.setAttribute("id", "subchaptertitle");
item2.textContent = row.Subchapter;

// add the subchapter as a childnode to the parentnode (var item)
rows.appendChild(item);
item.appendChild(item2);
```

Append item to the `<div id="database">` (variable rows) and item2 to `<p id="chaptertitle">` (variable item).